# Make curdate() as parameter

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to SELECT my "date-update" record with curdate(), my date-update record has a TIMESTAMP Data Type. And I want to filter it by Date exactly, anyone can help me?
I try this on my PHP Program and MySQL but it returns on an empty results..

"SELECT * FROM goods WHERE date_update like '%curdate()%'"

Answer (score 1):

Here is the right way to write the query:

```
SELECT *
FROM goods
WHERE date_update >= curdate() and date_update < curdate() + interval 1 day;
```

If `date_update` has no time component, then use:

```
SELECT *
FROM goods
WHERE date_update = curdate();
```

Comment: any isuue with using `WHERE DATE(date_update) = curdate();` if date_update includes time

Comment: @Dagon . . . The query won't use an index for the filtering.